# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime from dataset

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net

I have a dataset from SQL server which bound the gridview on aspx page. I post the date on webpage by using the below code:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("date1")).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")  %>'
```

The datetime is on SQL sever is 2015-12-06 00:00:00.000 that showing as  2015/06/12 on webpage. The correct date should be 2015/12/06 (Dec 6 2015). I have globalization on webconfig.

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US"/>
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: What is in the `date1` control? Is that the correct date from the database?

Comment: @ekolis Sorry, There is typo on my question. I corrected it. The date is in SQL in 2015-12-06 00:00:00.000 . The webpage shows as 2016/06/12. It is mixed up the month and day. It looks like the Visual studio doesn't read the date as same as SQL server. The date1 is column name from SQL dataset

Comment: Is `date1` a string or date column?  If it's a date why do you need Convert.ToDateTime`?

Comment: Sql Server should have the date persisted in a `DateTime` or `DateTime2` or `Date` type (not `varchar` or `text`). The display in sql server, therefor, should not matter. The returned instance from Sql Server should be of type `System.DateTime` in .net. You can then use `ToString` to display it as you see fit as it should be a presentation layer function and never anything deeper than that (*in the program stack*).

Comment: OK, so it's just swapping the month and the day, then, not getting 6 and 3 mixed up entirely? If you already checked the locale setting in web.config, how about checking the SQL Server setting to make sure they're consistent?

Comment: @Igor I recommend turning that into an answer.

Comment: I hear what Igor is saying.  Please post if this solved the problem.  He posts knowingly.

Comment: An interesting diagnostic step would be to pull the date field twice.  Once where you convert it to character values on the Sql Server, the other where you use your existing ASP method and see if you get the same date value......

Answer (score 19):

SQL Server should have the date persisted in one of the following types and never as anything else (*by anything else I am referring to `varchar`, `text`, `int`, `BigInt`, or anything else "creative"*)

- `DateTime2`
- `DateTime`
- `Date`
- `DateTimeOffset`

*For more types please refer to [Date and Time Data Types and Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx#DateandTimeDataTypes)*

The display in SQL Server, therefore, should never matter because there is no actual display or formatting associated with the type. What you happen to see in the query window in SSMS does have formatting but only because it has to be displayed some how, this formatting is usually done in ISO8601 notation and has nothing to do with how the instance is actually persisted.

The returned instance in your .NET code from Sql Server should be of type `System.DateTime` or `System.DateTimeOffset`, the latter if you are also using `DateTimeOffset` in Sql Server which persists the offset from UTC with the instance. You can then use `ToString()` with various formatting options to display the DateTime as you see fit. How a DateTime is displayed / formatted should always be a presentation layer function and never anything deeper than that in the program stack.

*See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) for the various format string options available for .net DateTime instances*

---

Coming back to the relevant code in the OP

```
<asp:Label Text='<%# Convert.ToDateTime(Eval("date1")).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") %>'
```

`Convert.ToDateTime` should be removed as the variable `date1` **should** already be a `DateTime` instance (*if you are following best practices as outlined above*). You can then call `ToString` on that instance directly with the desired format string.